# Hibiscus started drying suddenly

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, dryness, hibiscus

[image]I have hibiscus plant in my Terrence garden.  It started drying suddenly and about to die.
One of the hibiscus plant already died and looks like another is also started drying.

I tried uploading picture of the same but looks like some error.

Comment: It's very difficult to know what's wrong without photos I'm afraid... note that applying fertliizer to a stressed plant is never a good idea, but watering more might be, but its hard to say without being able to ID the problem.

Comment: @Bamboo i understand without photo it is hard to say, will try uploading after sometime as i am still facing some error while uploading photo.

Comment: In the meantime you could add more info - what variety of Hibiscus, is it planted in soil in the terrace or in a pot, what's the depth of soil if its not a pot, or how big is the pot, how long you've had the plant or when did you plant it, how much water does it get and so on...

Comment: It is planted in pot and Pot size is about 1 foot height and less then 1 foot perimeter. I planted it 4 years ago and its a first time its started drying. and one of the Red hibiscus already dried some days back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terrace gardens imply a hard surface attached to a building such as a balcony where the raised area overlooks something visually appealing and the garden consists of plants in planters and other boxes and pots massed together.

[image: An example of a terrace garden from Wikipedia (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Terrace_Garden_East-57th-St_New_York.jpg)]

An example of a terrace garden from Wikipedia (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Terrace_Garden_East-57th-St_New_York.jpg)

The big issue is that in contrast to an open garden the plants are confined to a smaller volume for the roots to grow in. This requires close attention to irrigation and feeding of the plants to ensure their continued health.

Hibiscus provide showy flowers but they are vigorous shrubs which will quickly fill a planter or pot. In addition if the planters lack free drainage the roots will suffer with rot if given too much water.

The drying indicates that something has gone wrong with the roots. Either they have filled the container and exhausted all the nourishment in that soil, or there is something wrong with the quality of the water used for irrigation; perhaps too much salt has built up, or overwatering has deprived the roots of air.

Since several plants are showing distress all at the same time you might give serious consideration to the plants having filled their growing place and are in need of replacement.

Comment: when saying about nourishment, what kind of fertilizer is suggested or any thing which can boost the soil health.

Comment: Fertilizing at this point is too late and inappropriate. As I indicated in my answer, I believe the way to go is replacement. The size of pot is determined by the design of your terrace garden, and also somewhat by your ability to perform maintenance on the pots. Removing the existing plants and soil and replacing them with fresh will give you another 4 years with components the same as they were.

Comment: Is there any chance I should try re poting the same plant in to other pot

Comment: I tried to repot my two hibiscus plants but it looks like stem of both the plants are rotten, what I can see, the roots are not spread  much that it running out space in pot but stem seems black and rotten near soil

Answer (score 1):

If it's been in the same pot for 4 years, it may well need potting on into something larger by now. Turn it out of its pot to check and if you see roots coiling round and round, it needs a larger container. When a plant runs out of sufficient root room, it starts to drop lower leaves, though growth at the top may continue; its also difficult for the plant to get sufficient water because the ratio of root to soil in the pot is wrong.

The soil in the pot looks as if its been disturbed; it's not evenly distributed and looks a bit lumpy, so have you been digging around in it for some reason? If you do repot, use new potting soil.

Otherwise, closely inspect the whole plant from top to bottom, including backs of leaves, to make sure there is no other problem with spider mites, insect infestation or disease.

Comment: The soil look disturbed as I dig the upper surface as I feel roots are getting rotten, I am inspecting it since few days and there are no insects. I am not putting any fertilizer as of now but watering a little as I feel this may be drying due to less water.  But no luck with digging or water even.

Comment: Turn it out of its pot to inspect the roots, but try not to damage them. Repot if necessary